# Visual studio compile output format

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, compiler-construction

When compiling a C++ application with VisualStudio I noticed that each output line has a number in front of it. What does the "\d>" stand for?

Example:

```
4>ContentTimecodeConverter.cpp                                                                                               
1>avus_mpeg_stream_out.obj : warning LNK4221: no public symbols found; archive member will be inaccessible                   
4>ContentTarget.cpp                                                                                                                                                                                         
4>ContentBrowserWidget.cpp                                                                                                   
1>Build log was saved at "file://d:\compile\release\libabc\BuildLog.htm"                                                  
1>libabc - 0 error(s), 1 warning(s)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have concurrent building enabled, an option that enables building multiple projects at the same time.  Each build running on one of the cores you have.  Which inevitably causes their output to get intermingled.  The number helps you keep track of which project produced the message.

It is configured with Tools + Options, Projects and Solutions, Build and Run, "maximum number of parallel build projects" setting.

It is a source of build breaks if you don't set the project dependencies correctly.